# Complexity of quantum simulation

Tags: quantum-information

Richard Feynman showed that [Quantum simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_simulator) on a Turing machine will have an exponential slowdown. If that is so, does this put quantum simulation outside of P (complexity class)? I thought quantum simulation was polynomially possible on quantum computers, but there is still no proof that BQP is strictly bigger than P. So either quantum simulation has not been shown to lie outside of P, or it is not in BQP. I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Did Feynman gave a formal proof for that? Can you cite it?

Comment: The only thing I can find is a transcription of a key note he gave, where he suggests it: Simulating physics with computers, Richard Feynman. He does not give a formal proof I think. I take it there haven't been any formal proofs since?

Comment: It is well known that simulating quantum models is not *necessarily* hard, e.g. stabilizer quantum mechanics, Gaussian continuous-variable quantum mechanics, or one-dimensional spin systems satisfying an area law, can all be simulated with polynomial overhead. (I suppose Feynman was not aware of these examples when he made his famous proposal.) Computer scientists have various reasons to believe that there *should* exist quantum simulations which are hard  (i.e. not in $P$), but there is still no proof.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: Are you saying that there is no known example of a quantum system that is not in _P_ or that there is no known proof that a non-naive algorithm can not be in _P_? I am never certain about what these statements mean.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, nor am I really qualified to answer, but I'll have a crack. As far as I know, no quantum algorithm has been proven to lie outside of P. The best example of an algorithm which is expected to be hard is probably [boson sampling](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3245).  There is also no known example of a (local) quantum Hamiltonian whose simulation is provably outside P, since this would be a quantum algorithm not in P. I do expect various contrived classical algorithms have been proven to lie outside of P (and also thus outside NP), however.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: Thanks! This is a non-trivial subject, for sure. I'll have to read more.

Comment: @CuriousOne Basically, any quantum mechanical problem can be simulated classically using a polynomial amount of memory (basically, using a path integral), a class known as PSPACE.  It is not known whether PSPACE is strictly larger than P.  So if you could prove for a quantum problem that it is outside P, you would have also solved a long-standing open problem in complexity theory.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: In other words, the quantum problem leads us back to the unsolved mathematical problem? That solidifies my initial assumption that Feynman was slightly out of his depth when he spoke about the issue. I can understand why he would have (naively) made this kind of comment, though. Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 7):

Feynman never showed that quantum simulation has an exponential cost. He probably mentioned that it seemed to be the case.

In complexity theory, it's surprisingly hard to prove lower bounds on the cost of solving a problem or to prove separations between complexity classes. The behavior of computer programs is wildly diverse, and eliminating *all* of them as candidates is pretty tricky. For example, complexity theorists trying to resolve P-vs-NP have proved lower bounds... [on *how hard the proof will be*](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/alg.pdf).

Classical vs quantum, i.e. [BPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_%28complexity%29) vs [BQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQP), is one of the many examples of a complexity class pair in the "conjectured to be different, but no one knows how to prove it" bucket.

As an example of why this is tricky, suppose you conjectured that quantum computers have a space advantage over classical computers. That BQP $\not\subset$ PSPACE. You make all kinds of arguments about the number of amplitudes being exponentially large, etc, etc. Except we know that, actually, BQP $\subset$ PSPACE. You can compute a single output amplitude without using much space by iterating over all the possible paths contributing to it. Use that to iterate over the outputs, and return one probabilistically.

Proving there's nothing that does for time what path integrals did for space is hard.